# camel bindy decimal pattern

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I need a point as decimal separator in my output file. When using this pattern :

```
@DataField(pos = 12, precision = 1, pattern = "####.#")  Double amount;
```

with for ex. input: 1491.84
the output is strangely (no decimal): **1491.**

if I change my pattern with a comma instead of a point :

```
@DataField(pos = 12, precision = 1, pattern = "####,#")  Double amount;
```

input: 1491.84
output: **1491,8**
then it works but why not for the point separator ?

Comment: System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
fr_FR

Comment: I understand if I set Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en_UK"));
it works

Comment: Thanks for the info, changing to the right Locale solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at your `Locale`.

There is a common difference between English locales (like `en_UK` or `en_US`) and some European localse (like German or French) in the use of `.` and `,` for decimal separator and decimal point.

Perhaps setting your locale to an english variant would help?